# JSON object being reordered by Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I have a rather large JSON object being generated via PHP. It creates a PHP object out of a database, with keys that are integers, ie 1-100. These keys are not in that order though, they are in a random order, such as 55, 72, 5, 8, 14, 32, 64, etc. I then use json_encode to output the object as JSON. I then use an AJAX call to grab that JSON and store it in a variable. However, that variable has the JSON object in order 1-100, instead of the sorted order above.

Any ideas why it's doing that, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Please improve this question by showing some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys within an object aren't technically ordered. That you expect them to be in a particular order is a mistake in data structure. A JSON parser will interpret numerical keys as array positions.

this

```
{
    55: "foo",
    29: "bar",
    ...
}
```

is semantically the same as:

```
object[55] = "foo"
object[29] = "bar"
```

which is:

```
[
    ...
    "bar" //index 29
    ...
    "foo" //index 55
    ...
]
```

Instead, you should separate the order and the identify of your objects:

```
[
    {id: 55, content: "foo"},
    {id: 29, content: "bar"},
    ...
]
```

Comment: The last part "use an array" is repetitive.  It could be omitted, as the previous example is an array of objects.  A good alternative would be to teach him how about [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to put the array of objects in whatever order he would like when it is out of order.

Comment: The array of objects is an order-indeterminant collection, while the final array is ordered. I'll edit to make that clear.

Comment: Any Array in Javascript is ordered. It is Object that contains key/value pairs and is unordered.  Every Array has an integer index.

Comment: You are correct. In this case the order of insertion of objects will be preserved, as will the OPs id numbers.

Comment: I think this might be the solution I'm looking for but I'm not sure how to make that work. My object already has the id as key/value in each one. The problem is I loop through the object appending to an element and need the object in the right order before hand.

Comment: @sharf in this solution, if you loop through the array, it will give you the objects in the order they are in your JSON

Comment: @PatrickGunderson Perfect. I'm not understanding how to do that though. To give a brief example of my JSON, {"55":{"id":55,"name":"Curse of the Beast","rarity":6,"type":3,"tier":4,"prime":660,"ecost":320,"ccost":120,"pcost":0,"upgrade":0,"set":0,"power":84,"ihero":41,"khero":42,"upg":"","atts":{"1":{"desc":"For 3<\/span> sec. turns an enemy hero into a beast, which attacks a hero.
The beast cannot move slower or faster."}}}}

Comment: Make 2 small changes: change your outer object to an array: change the `{}` to `[]` and eliminate the keys. then you'll get the object back in order. The problem may be in your PHP JSON encoder or data structure. if in PHP you are assigning the key `obj[myObj->id]=myObj;` you may want to just add in order `obj[i]=myObj;`

Comment: But then I wouldn't be able to reference it like object[55].name would I?

Comment: If you want to preserve order, then `object[55]` is the 55th object you put into the array. if you want the order to be different from ID, you can either change the id to a non-number `object["num55"]` which will maintain order of insertion, or you can loop through all the elements until you find the one with `id == 55`. [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) has a function for this so its less tedious.

Comment: It sounds like you more or less want me to go back to my original set up. In which, the order was set 1-x in the display order, and then I stored the id and other information since I can't use jQuery to "find" an object value based on a sub value...I suppose the best solution would be to stop trying to force the database ID and build based on the properly sorted indexes instead.

Comment: OK so you have jquery, that's good to know. Please tell me what your original attributes look like and what you're trying to find. Jquery may be more capable to solve this problem than you think.

Comment: I use several functions to filter which elements are displayed. I use the tier, rarity, set, id(used to be index), ihero, khero attributes for that. Then I use the type attribute in a lot of functions to determine what should be done. I thought it would be easier to just mark an element with the ID and then reference the object rather then storing all the information on the element, because those elements are copied/moved to different locations in the DOM quite frequently.

Comment: If you're setting the ID internal to the object, why can't you use that to search against, instead of all those attributes? (also underscore makes it easy to search against all those attributes) It's ok to have separate `order` and `id` attributes.

Comment: Ignorance on my part, I can't figure out how to get sister values. So if if object[1].id = 3 and and object[2].id = 55 and I need object[2].name (or id 55's name) I don't know how to do that. And was under the impression that it was impossible without looping through them all searching, which seems very inefficient.

Comment: You are correct, it's not the most efficient, but unless you're doing this loop against 100000000 objects it will barely tax the processor in modern JS (even on mobile) interpreters. If you wanted to be more processor efficient, you could make two parallel arrays, one ordered by insertion, the other ordered by id, although that's less memory efficient. You could also make two arrays, one ordered by id, and the other, a list of ids in the order of insertion.

Comment: I considered both of those. I don't have time to try them all out right now, but I think I'll try and fix how I store/reference things rather than forcing my set up. I Will probably end up changing to just using the ordered indexes instead of IDs. Thanks

Comment: *"A JSON parser will interpret numerical keys as array positions."* No it won't. An object is not an array, no matter what keys it has. The fact that most browsers order numeric properties is an implementation detail.

Comment: In JS objects keys that are numbers and keys that are "numbers" are treated as the same thing, so `obj[55] === obj["55"]` arrays are just objects with numerical keys.

Comment: @PatrickGunderson: Yes, I didn't deny that. Please read my comment again. Every array is an object with numeric keys, **but** not every object with numeric keys is an array. That's what you are claiming in your answer (kind of).

Answer (score 5):

JSON objects have no specific order and are not guaranteed to keep the order you put things in.  If you want keys in an order, you should put them in an array which will maintain order.  If you want an ordered set of key/value pairs, you can use several different forms.

The simplest would be to just have a single array that is an alternating set of key, value:

```
var data = ["key1", "value1", "key2", "value2",...];
```

Or, you could do an array of objects:

```
var data = [{key: "key1", data: "value1"}, {key: "key2", data: "value2"}, {...}]
```

Comment: My Object originated as just an index (1-100) with several values, including the ID, and even a few nested objects/arrays. The problem is that it was requiring my code to store too many attributes in elements in the DOM. Instead I thought I would make the index the id so I could call object[id].name, etc. However, I need the information to generate objects that are appended to an element. That is why maintaining the order is important.

Comment: Actually, your original problem is pretty interesting. You should post a SO question about that.

Comment: @sharf What do you mean it required too many attributes in elements? I don't think there's a practical limit.

Comment: @PatrickGunderson No, there wasn't a limit. The issue is that searching and matching by attributes was becoming tedious and thought it would be nicer to reference the object for all info, and just need to know the ID as I go.

Comment: searching and matching by attributes is tedious! Have you looked into using any helper libraries that have functions for this type of thing built-in?