# $.parseJSON changes associative array order

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, sorting, parsing

I receive an alphabetically sorted (by values) json through AJAX:

```
console.log(data);
```

which shows:

```
{"0":"","23":"Granta","20":"Vesta SW Cross","24":"Zetta"}
```

but when I parse it:

```
var models = $.parseJSON(data);
console.log(models);
```

it breaks the alphabetical order and shows:

```
Object { 0: "", 20: "Vesta SW Cross", 23: "Granta", 24: "Zetta" }
```

then I populate a select element:

```
$.each(models, function(key, value) {
    model.append($('<option></option>').text(value).val(key));
});
```

is there any way to sort these options alphabetically by values again?

Comment: Where is your data coming from? Looks like it's from an array that's been sorted and filtered without re-indexing. A small change to your backend could give you an array with guaranteed ordering

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON object being reordered by Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966722/json-object-being-reordered-by-javascript)

Comment: the data is coming already sorted in a proper order, it's sorted by values. the problem is the parsed object is not indexed, I need to sort it alphabetically again. The order is not important, I just need alphabetical sorting by values

Comment: Do you control the backend code? Is it PHP? If you answered yes, a small change to use `array_values()` could fix your problem where it most makes sense to fix it, eg change `echo json_encode($models);` to `echo json_encode(array_values($models));`

Comment: Otherwise, try `const options = Object.values(models).sort()`

Comment: yes, I'm already outputting the json from the backend with echo json_encode($models); Looks like models = Object.values(models).sort(); works. Thank you.

Comment: You should **really** fix the problem at the source

Comment: Oops, the sort only sorts the values, but it doesn't keep the index. I need the options sorted alphabetically but with the index kept as well. The source is fine, it is already sorted alphabetically before being passed to json encoding. The returned array is associative and it has to be kept that because I use both the keys and values.

Comment: This is the input from backend: {"0":"","23":"Granta","20":"Vesta SW Cross","24":"Zetta"} - it's already sorted by values with associated keys

Comment: I've added a client-side map/sort solution below. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* do everything client-side, you can convert and sort your original response

```js
$.getJSON(url).done(models => {
  const sorted = Object.entries(models).sort(([k1, v1], [k2, v2]) =>
      v1.localeCompare(v2))
  model.append(sorted.map(([value, text]) => $('<option>', { value, text })))
})
```

---

Otherwise, I would suggest fixing this at the source to return a more comprehensive data model.

For example, assuming you have something like

```php
$models = [
    0  => '',
    23 => 'Granta',
    20 => 'Vesta SW Cross',
    24 => 'Zetta'
];
```

Map this to a better data structure, eg

```php
$data = [];
foreach ($models as $value => $text) {
    $data[] = ['value' => $value, 'text' => $text];
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

This will produce a JSON string like

```js
[
  {
    "value": 0,
    "text": ""
  },
  {
    "value": 23,
    "text": "Granta"
  },
  {
    "value": 20,
    "text": "Vesta SW Cross"
  },
  {
    "value": 24,
    "text": "Zetta"
  }
]
```

which is in order and contains all the data you need

```js
$.getJSON(url).done(models => {
  model.append(models.map(props => $('<option>', props)))
})
```